# Why is this counting the number of words incorrectly?

Tags: java, counting

public static void words(String text) {
int numWords = 1;

```
    for (int charNum = 0; charNum < text.length(); charNum++) {
        char letter = text.charAt(charNum);
        
        if(charNum + 1 < text.length()) {
            char nextLetter = text.charAt(charNum + 1);
            if(letter == '.' || letter == ':' || letter == ';' || letter == '?' || letter == '!'|| letter == ' ' || letter == '\n' || letter == '\t') {
                if(nextLetter != '.' || nextLetter != ':' || nextLetter != ';' || nextLetter != '?' || nextLetter != '!'|| nextLetter != ' ' || nextLetter != '\n' || nextLetter != '\t')
                    numWords += 1;
            }   
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Number of words: " + numWords);
}
```

The String "Is this_one_long_word or several??? What do you think?? Too much" should print 10 words and "!This uses periods.as.word.delimiters and can be tricky." should print 10 words.

This is the description: A word is sequence of one or more characters delimited by white space or by a sentence terminators (period, colon, semicolon, question mark, exclamation point), whether or not it is an actual English word. White space is defined as a space, tab ( '\t'), a new line character ('\n'), and the end of the String itself. Again this gives some results that may not make sense. For example the text "I_don't_like_to_use_SPACES-EVER!" has a single word: I_don't_like_to_use_SPACES-EVER.

Answer (score 2):

The following line is always true:

```java
if(nextLetter != '.' || nextLetter != ':' || nextLetter != ';' || nextLetter != '?' || nextLetter != '!'|| nextLetter != ' ' || nextLetter != '\n' || nextLetter != '\t')
```

Change it to:

```java
if(nextLetter != '.' && nextLetter != ':' && nextLetter != ';' && nextLetter != '?' && nextLetter != '!'&& nextLetter != ' ' && nextLetter != '\n' && nextLetter != '\t')
```

Starting your count to `int numwords = 1;` will give you an incorrect count. Start at 0.

Your second input is starting with `!` which is adding a word to the count.
You have to check if the character after a terminator is a letter or not to avoid this behavior:

```java
 public static void words(String text) {
        int numWords = 0;
        final String wordTerminators = ".:;?! \n\t";
        for (int charNum = 0; charNum < text.length() - 1; charNum++) {
            char letter = text.charAt(charNum);
           
            char nextLetter = text.charAt(charNum + 1);
            if (wordTerminators.contains(letter + "")) {
                if (!wordTerminators.contains(nextLetter + "") && !(nextLetter+"").matches("[A-Za-z]"))
                    numWords += 1;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Number of words: " + numWords);
    }
```

Here is a cleaner version of my solution:

```java
    public static void words(String text) {
        int numWords = 0;
        
        String[] splitted = text.split("[.:;?! \\n\\t]+");
        for (String word : splitted) {
            if (word.length() > 0)
                numWords++;
        }
        System.out.println("Number of words: " + numWords);
    }
```

Both methods outputs are:

```
Number of words: 10
Number of words: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid conditions in last `if` (most nested one) - you need to make sure that next character (called `nextLetter` in your code) is none of the characters you check but you use OR instead of AND conditions there so it's always true (because character cannot be two different characters at the same time).

So you can change this `if` to:

```
if(nextLetter != '.' && nextLetter != ':' && nextLetter != ';' && nextLetter != '?' && nextLetter != '!'&& nextLetter != ' ' && nextLetter != '\n' && nextLetter != '\t')
```

and it will count the words correctly. Make sure that you count also the first word because currently if you start with `numWords` set to zero, it will print `9` for your example instead of `10` - because first word is not counted. So you should count it as well.

Btw. Your code could be significantly simplified in several ways, you can also use alternative approaches like `split` function (from String).